# Adwhirl Custom Event with JumpTap

Tags: android, ads, adwhirl

I was looking to add an unsupported Adwhirl ad provider to my Android application.  It looks like I need to create a custom event for Adwhirl. Does anyone have an example of an Adwhirl custom event that I could use for reference?